# Network connection between 2 Docker Container (JBOSS/DATABASE)

Tags: postgresql, docker, jboss, connection, ansible

i'm trying to get a connection between 2 Docker container.
The first one is a postgres database and the second one is a jboss.

I'm using ansible and here is my Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: start postgresql
    docker:
      name: mypostgres
      image: MYIMAGE_POSTGRES
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
  expose:
    - 5432:5432
  state: started
  env:
    DB_USER: "user"
    DB_PASS: "pass"
    DB_NAME: "name"

  - name: start jboss
    docker:
      name: jboss
  image: MYIMAGE_JBOSS
  ports:
    - 1099:1099
  expose:
    - 1099:1099
  state: running
  env:
      POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR: "172.17.0.2"
      POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT: 5432
      HIBERNATE_CREATE_DDL: ""
      DB_NAME: "name"
      DB_USER: "user"
      DB_PASS: "pass"
```

If i start both docker images, there is no connection between database and jboss.
Is there anything i had missed, in my configuration?

Thanks a lot,
Pascal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link the postgres container to the jboss one. For doing that, use the `link` option

```
...

docker:
  name: jboss
  image: MYIMAGE_JBOSS
  ports:
    - 1099:1099
  expose:
   - 1099:1099
  links:
   -mypostgres
  state: running
    env:
      POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR: "mypostgres"
      POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT: 5432
      HIBERNATE_CREATE_DDL: ""
      DB_NAME: "name"
      DB_USER: "user"
      DB_PASS: "pass"
...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help.
Know i can connect with psql.... to the database. My Jboss throws an exception that he can't connect.

I will investigate this. Any ideas maybe?

Comment: I suggest you to ask a new question with the exception you are getting and some other relevant info in order to be able to give you some help.  By the way,  if my answer really help you,  please accept it as the correct one